# Not able to export data in separate directories in SQL Developer for Oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to export n number of files from SQL developer for oracle. But when I select separate directories option to export. The data gets exported only in a single folder.

How can we achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're exporting TABLES, that's expected. If you read the help

> Separate Directories: A directory for each object type being exported
> is created

So all the TABLEs would be exported to a single directory.

And then VIEWs would be exported to another directory.

[image]

If you want to export a bunch of tables and have each file(table) go into it's own directory, I think you would need to script that in a worksheet with some SPOOL and HOST commands.